# TimeLine vis.js multiple columns as groups

Tags: javascript, vis.js

In vis.js / timeline you can group your data as shown in this example : http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/groups/groups.html

Is there anyway to add more data to these groups, and that for each field an extra column is added to the grid ?

For example in http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/groups/groups.html currently you see the groups "Aston", "John" and "Lee"

But I also want to see these peoples lastnames. But in a 2nd column.

So you have something like

```
---------------------------------------------------
|John   | Doe      | *graph data*                 | 
|--------------------------------------------------
|Aston  | Johnson  | *graph data*                 |
|--------------------------------------------------
|Lee    | Parker   | *graph data*                 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

So I can insert n columns before the actual graph data...

It would be really nice if I also could specify which headers to use for each of these columns.

Comment: I need same feature for one of my application. Please add a solution if you have found one

Comment: I used <table> tags for the label of each group.

After rendering I checked for the larged columns in each of the tables. And then set these sizes to all of the tables.

This way the data is aligned correctyle. But no table lines are drawn.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I 'm planning to use similar approach.
Did you use same approach to handle header titles?